# What is the sentence starter, "as a result"? Is it a transitional word?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What part of speech is "as a result"? Is it transitional or a conjunction or neither.

Comment: Sometimes [transitional words](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Transitions.html) are also conjunctions. This is a transitional word of cause or effect. If it's still confusing to you, you might want to ask on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour). It's very helpful for questions about the English language.

Comment: @medica Brilliant list. I will purloin it.

Answer (score 1):

*As a result,* (comma normally required, especially at the beginning of a sentence) is a fixed phrase, not a word, and therefore its part of speech is irrelevant. Like most prepositional phrases, however, it functions adverbially.

It is short for "as a result of what I just told you"; and it means there is a cause-effect relation between the last thing I said and what I'm saying now.